# How to delete emails from cpanel using php fopen

Tags: php, email, cpanel

I have my domains in one hosting account and emails in another. I need to delete emails using php code. Using fopen, how can I delete emails from one hosting account whose domains are in another.

Answer (score 0):

I think fopen function can open a file to read or write but can't delete, but may be discussion in [this thread](http://hostmonsterforums.com/showthread.php?3964-Cpanel-PHP-class-delete-email) could give you any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
@fopen("http://".$cpuser.":".$cppass."@".$domain.":2082/frontend/x3/mail/realdelpop.html?domain=".$domain."&email=".$email, "r") OR 
    die("Error.");
```

Comment: $cpuser = ""; //Your cPanel Username
$cppass = ""; //Your cPanel Password
$domain = ""; //ex:mysite.com
$delemail = "";

Comment: Some explanation behind how this works would be awesome.  Also, a bit of formatting care would be nice.

Comment: Why surpress errors on `@fopen`? That just makes debugging difficult.

Comment: Also, if cPanel lets you do a `GET` request to delete stuff in the panel, it really reinforces my "cPanel should burn in hell for all eternity" feelings.